# Helm chart unavailable error while deploying airflow on eks cluster

Tags: charts, airflow, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to deploy airflow on the EKS cluster using the helm chart. I had configured flux to sync the GitHub repo to the EKS cluster.

[image: Below logs i am getting through flux operator pod]

```
ts=2021-07-16T16:02:47.654523409Z caller=release.go:85 component=release release=airflow-dev targetNamespace=dev resource=dev:helmrelease/airflow helmVersion=v3 error="failed to prepare chart for release: chart unavailable: looks like \"https://github.com/marclamberti/airflow-eks-helm-chart.git\" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: failed to fetch https://github.com/marclamberti/airflow-eks-helm-chart.git/index.yaml : 404 Not Found"
ts=2021-07-16T16:03:47.598750764Z caller=release.go:79 component=release release=airflow-dev targetNamespace=dev resource=dev:helmrelease/airflow helmVersion=v3 info="starting sync run"
ts=2021-07-16T16:03:47.640613252Z caller=release.go:85 component=release release=airflow-dev targetNamespace=dev resource=dev:helmrelease/airflow helmVersion=v3 error="failed to prepare chart for release: chart unavailable: looks like \"https://github.com/marclamberti/airflow-eks-helm-chart.git\" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: failed to fetch https://github.com/marclamberti/airflow-eks-helm-chart.git/index.yaml : 404 Not Found"
ts=2021-07-16T16:04:47.600721115Z caller=release.go:79 component=release release=airflow-dev targetNamespace=dev resource=dev:helmrelease/airflow helmVersion=v3 info="starting sync run"
ts=2021-07-16T16:04:47.65458295Z caller=release.go:85 component=release release=airflow-dev targetNamespace=dev resource=dev:helmrelease/airflow helmVersion=v3 error="failed to prepare chart for release: chart unavailable: looks like \"https://github.com/marclamberti/airflow-eks-helm-chart.git\" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: failed to fetch https://github.com/marclamberti/airflow-eks-helm-chart.git/index.yaml : 404 Not Found"
ts=2021-07-16T16:05:47.600250549Z caller=release.go:79 component=release release=airflow-dev targetNamespace=dev resource=dev:helmrelease/airflow helmVersion=v3 info="starting sync run"
ts=2021-07-16T16:05:47.778319443Z caller=release.go:85 component=release release=airflow-dev targetNamespace=dev resource=dev:helmrelease/airflow helmVersion=v3 error="failed to prepare chart for release: chart unavailable: looks like \"https://github.com/marclamberti/airflow-eks-helm-chart.git\" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: failed to fetch https://github.com/marclamberti/airflow-eks-helm-chart.git/index.yaml : 404 Not Found"
ts=2021-07-16T16:05:57.703391379Z caller=git.go:209 component=gitchartsync info="starting sync of git mirror" mirror=
ts=2021-07-16T16:05:57.709800453Z caller=release.go:79 component=release release=airflow-dev targetNamespace=dev resource=dev:helmrelease/airflow helmVersion=v3 info="starting sync run"
ts=2021-07-16T16:05:57.762605931Z caller=release.go:85 component=release release=airflow-dev targetNamespace=dev resource=dev:helmrelease/airflow helmVersion=v3 error="failed to prepare chart for release: chart unavailable: looks like \"https://github.com/apache/airflow\" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: failed to fetch https://github.com/apache/airflow/index.yaml : 404 Not Found"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe u want to use the official airflow helm chart.
this has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71156500/14091289