# Helm Chart Release Official AIrflow

Tags: airflow, kubernetes-helm, flux

I was wondering how to write an helm release yaml file using the official airflow helm chart and overwriting the values.yaml file.
I'm trying to use this config file to deploy airflow with flux on a kubernetes cluster.

I tried :

```
apiVersion: helm.fluxcd.io/v1
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: airflow
  namespace: dev
spec:
  releaseName: airflow-dev
  chart:
    repository: https://airflow.apache.org
    name: airflow
```

Did I miss something ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a helm resource artifact like this. lets name it as `charts.yml`

```
apiVersion: source.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1beta1
kind: HelmRepository
metadata:
  name: airflow
  namespace: flux
spec:
  interval: 1m
  url: https://airflow.apache.org
```

and then you can define your manifest as

```
apiVersion: helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta1
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: airflow
  namespace: dev
spec:
  interval: 5m
  chart:
    spec:
      chart: airflow
      sourceRef:
        kind: HelmRepository
        name: airflow
        namespace: flux
      interval: 1m
```

the flux version used is `flux version 0.27.0`

Comment: this helped me; i have a generic questions, how can i figure out the url for airflow's (or any other known services) `HelmRepository`? I was guessing it was this: https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/apache-airflow/airflow; and I always thought above would be the url for `kind: GitRepository`

Comment: also, i wonder if i can provide a file `for the values to override values.yaml of the chart` like we do in the procedural deployment approach (`kubectl apply -f my-values.yaml`); In other words, can I use `valuesFrom` defined in this API Reference: `https://fluxcd.io/flux/components/helm/api/` and put the values into the ConfigMap kind or is it a bad idea to use configMap for this purpose?